# How to open multiple instances using "standard__navItemPage" in a console app?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, pagereference, navigationmixin.navigate

In salesforce we are using

```
{
    type: 'standard__navItemPage',
    attributes: {
        apiName: 'MyCustomTabName'
    },
    state: {
        c__recordTypeDeveloperName : 'TestRT',
        c__anyRecordId : 'recordId'
    }
}
```

`MyCustomTabName` is a App page, which holds few custom LWCs. It reads URL params passed and loads data dynamically.

The problem is this is shown as a footer component on a tabbed LWC. Now for the first time the data loads properly. Is there a way where I can create multiple instances of this page dynamically and open a new page always?
Currently it just redirects to the same opened page, even when trying to navigate by changing the page params.

Is wrapping this App page under aura?